# Rails 3 - Is this SQL safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and I baked this little login controller.

```
  def create
    username = params[:user].downcase
    user = User.where("username = ? OR email = ?", username, username)[0]
    if user and user.check_password(params[:password], user.password, user.salt)
        cookies[:auth] = user.auth
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash.now.notice = 'Login failed'
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I am wondering if this is safe, or do I need to add some sanitization on top of username?

Comment: yes that is. a little advice would be to use `.first` instead of `[0]`. if you also want to show us check_password, then include it in the question.

Comment: Also you might want a look at this railscast about authentication http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

Comment: yeah I know about .first, but I prefer [0] :) Thanks for tutorial, I see it uses has_secure_password, but I prefer to do my own hashing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with ActiveRecord, `first` is a special method that will retrieve one record. Calling `[0]` on the scope may have the effect of loading *all* users and discarding all but the first. With normal arrays the difference is purely a matter of style.

Comment: Thats a good point. In this particular example however I can still afford to use [0] since it will ever only fetch 1 row or be nil. In fact, I needen't use [0] or .first here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the provided escaping facility, which is what the `?` placeholders are for, then you should be safe from SQL injection bugs **provided** you are at the latest version of Rails and other critical components.

An example of safe code:

```
User.where(:username => arg)
User.where('username=?', arg)
```

An example of **unsafe** code:

```
User.where('username="#{arg}"')
```

Note that you have to use string interpolation to create a SQL injection bug. These should be pretty obvious when auditing code and there is rarely an excuse to do this. If you must, for whatever reason, please be absolutely certain that whatever value you are injecting is properly escaped or comes from a white-list of known-good values.

Older versions of Rails and some of the popular pagination and authentication tools have had SQL injection bugs that can be exploited. Be sure that you have current versions of these. If necessary, delete `Gemfile.lock` and do a clean `bundle install`.